# Microsoft API for parallel programming in C

Tags: c, winapi, parallel-processing

Is there any Microsoft API for parallel programing in C language ?

thanks for any answers,

bye

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they implement OpenMP version 2.  Start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Over-network-parallel? I guess not. But might be you are in search of threads:

http://www.relisoft.com/win32/active.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684254%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 2):

[Since Visual Studio 2005](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F4%2Fc%2Ff%2F4cfd0f76-8811-42c0-8ee1-d7d469a8abe7%2Fmathlibshpc_final.doc&rct=j&q=windows%20hpc%20visual%20c%2B%2B&ei=65HGTKTqDYuhOtjV5OII&usg=AFQjCNG0XFSVo9CKYjLy0uVfLzFNiGgztA&cad=rja), the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler has supported [OpenMP version 2](http://openmp.org/wp/), which is a "multi-platform shared-memory parallel programming" API for C. (And C++ as well as Fortran.)

Also see [this tutorial](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/c/f/4cfd0f76-8811-42c0-8ee1-d7d469a8abe7/ClassicHPCDevC++.docx) which describes both network and multiprocessor parallelism, quoting:

*"Written for the C and C++ developer, this tutorial walks you through the steps of designing, writing, debugging and profiling a parallel application for Windows HPC Server 2008".*

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Windows HPC Server version includes an implementation of MPI for distributed-memory programming.